# Trouble maintaining buffer position when using re-builder

Tags: buffers, regular-expressions, motion

I am having trouble maintaining my current location in a document while running the `re-builder` command in Emacs. In a long document the buffer moves to the top of the document whenever I run the `re-builder` command. I would like it to remain static so I can test the regexp I am working on (wherever it may be). I have then to then switch windows, relocate myself in the buffer, and then move the cursor again to re-builder to begin typing my regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```el
(define-advice reb-update-overlays
    (:around (orig-fun &rest args) save-window-excursion)
  "Advice for `reb-update-overlays' to inhibit window config changes."
  (save-window-excursion (apply orig-fun args)))

;; Remove with:
;; (advice-remove 'reb-update-overlays 'reb-update-overlays@save-window-excursion)
```

The `reb-auto-match-limit` user option may also be of note here (tangentially).